# The TextView gives out total 0 - Android

Tags: android, dynamic, row

I have a dynamic table row addind feature which consist of edit fields added .
I have to add each edit field value using TextWatcher feature and it adds up to get the final total .

But in this case I always get 0 as my final value, why is it so .

My code as seen below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mTripItemData.size(); i++)
    {

        TableRow row = new TableRow(Add_New_Expense_Activity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mDate = new TextView(this);
        mDate.setText(mTripItemData.get(i).getSTART_DATE().toString());

        mFrom = new TextView(this);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            mFrom.setText("HQ");
        }
        else
        {
            mFrom.setText(mTripItemData.get(i-1).getSTART_LOCATION());
        }

        mTo = new TextView(this);
        mTo.setText(mTripItemData.get(i).getSTART_LOCATION());

        mTravelMode = new TextView(this);


        for (int j = 0; j < mVehicleData.size(); j++)
        {

            if (mTripItemData.get(i).getVEHICAL_TYPE().equalsIgnoreCase(mVehicleData.get(j).getPKWKL()))
            {

                mTravelMode.setText(mVehicleData.get(j).getTEXT25());

            }

        }

        mKm = new TextView(this);
        mKm.setText(mTripItemData.get(i).getEXP_RUN_KM().toString());

        mTotalExp = new TextView(this);
        mTotalExp.setText("0");


        // Travel Fare 

        mTravelFare = new EditText(this);
        mTravelFare.setText("0");
        mTravelFare.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });



        mCarVehicleExp = new EditText(this);
        mCarVehicleExp.setText("0");
        mCarVehicleExp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });


        mConveyance = new EditText(this);
        mConveyance.setText("0");
        mConveyance.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });



        mLodgingNBoarding = new EditText(this);
        mLodgingNBoarding.setText("0");
        mLodgingNBoarding.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });






        mDailyAllowance = new EditText(this);
        mDailyAllowance.setText("0");
        mDailyAllowance.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });






        mTelExp = new EditText(this);
        mTelExp.setText("0");
        mTelExp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });





        mOtherExp = new EditText(this);
        mOtherExp.setText("0");
        mOtherExp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mTotalExp .setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))); 

            }
        });





        row.addView(mDate);
        row.addView(mFrom);
        row.addView(mTo);
        row.addView(mTravelMode);
        row.addView(mKm);
        row.addView(mTravelFare);
        row.addView(mCarVehicleExp);
        row.addView(mConveyance);
        row.addView(mLodgingNBoarding);
        row.addView(mDailyAllowance);
        row.addView(mTelExp);
        row.addView(mOtherExp);
        row.addView(mTotalExp);




        mExpenseTable.addView(row);

    }
```

Comment: log what this is returning `Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString()))`

Comment: Gives out 0 .. its like every time a TextWatcher is called the there is 0 the edit Text

Comment: are the values setted to your edittext? try simply getting one value and logging it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quite given enough context to see exactly what's going on, but it looks like you're updating your member variables each time through your `for` loop, so your `TextWatcher`s will only operate on your last `TableRow`.  I think what you need to do is instead of updating your member variables like:

```
mTravelFare = new EditText(this);
```

do this so that you declare a new `travelFare` each time through the loop:

```
final EditText travelFare = new EditText(this);
```

and then in your `TextWatcher`, replace the member variable `mTravelFare` with the local final variable `travelFare` where you're adding the contents of the `EditText`s.

Answer (score 0):

I quite did my R&D and got the answer .

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mTripItemData.size(); i++)
    {

        TableRow row = new TableRow(Add_New_Expense_Activity.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mDate = new TextView(this);
        mDate.setText(mTripItemData.get(i).getSTART_DATE().toString());

        mFrom = new TextView(this);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            mFrom.setText("HQ");
        }
        else
        {
            mFrom.setText(mTripItemData.get(i-1).getSTART_LOCATION());
        }

        mTo = new TextView(this);
        mTo.setText(mTripItemData.get(i).getSTART_LOCATION());

        mTravelMode = new TextView(this);


        for (int j = 0; j < mVehicleData.size(); j++)
        {

            if (mTripItemData.get(i).getVEHICAL_TYPE().equalsIgnoreCase(mVehicleData.get(j).getPKWKL()))
            {

                mTravelMode.setText(mVehicleData.get(j).getTEXT25());

            }

        }

        mKm = new TextView(this);
        mKm.setText(mTripItemData.get(i).getEXP_RUN_KM().toString());

        final TextView mTotalExp = new TextView(this);
        mTotalExp.setText("0");


        // Travel Fare 

        final EditText mTravelFare = new EditText(this);
        mTravelFare.setText("0");


        final EditText mCarVehicleExp = new EditText(this);
        mCarVehicleExp.setText("0");


        final EditText mConveyance = new EditText(this);
        mConveyance.setText("0");

        final EditText  mLodgingNBoarding = new EditText(this);
        mLodgingNBoarding.setText("0");

        final EditText  mDailyAllowance = new EditText(this);
        mDailyAllowance.setText("0");


        final EditText mTelExp = new EditText(this);
        mTelExp.setText("0");


        final EditText mOtherExp = new EditText(this);
        mOtherExp.setText("0");




        mTravelFare.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });



        mCarVehicleExp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });



        mConveyance.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });




        mLodgingNBoarding.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });







        mDailyAllowance.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });







        mTelExp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });






        mOtherExp.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {// TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int travelFare = 0;
                int carVehicleExp = 0;
                int conveyanceExp = 0;
                int lodgBoardExp = 0; 
                int dailyAllExp = 0;
                int otherExp = 0;
                int telExp = 0;
                int totalExp = 0;

                if(!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(""))&&!(mTravelFare.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    travelFare = Integer.parseInt(mTravelFare.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    carVehicleExp = Integer.parseInt(mCarVehicleExp.getText().toString());
                }


                if(!mConveyance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mConveyance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    conveyanceExp = Integer.parseInt(mConveyance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    lodgBoardExp = Integer.parseInt(mLodgingNBoarding.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    dailyAllExp = Integer.parseInt(mDailyAllowance.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mOtherExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    otherExp = Integer.parseInt(mOtherExp.getText().toString());
                }

                if(!mTelExp.getText().toString().equals("")&&!(mTelExp.getText().toString().equals(null)))
                {
                    telExp = Integer.parseInt(mTelExp.getText().toString());
                }



                totalExp = travelFare + carVehicleExp +conveyanceExp + lodgBoardExp + dailyAllExp + otherExp + telExp ;

                mTotalExp.setText(totalExp);}
        });





        row.addView(mDate);
        row.addView(mFrom);
        row.addView(mTo);
        row.addView(mTravelMode);
        row.addView(mKm);
        row.addView(mTravelFare);
        row.addView(mCarVehicleExp);
        row.addView(mConveyance);
        row.addView(mLodgingNBoarding);
        row.addView(mDailyAllowance);
        row.addView(mTelExp);
        row.addView(mOtherExp);
        row.addView(mTotalExp);




        mExpenseTable.addView(row);


    }
```